# Regular expression of Qt don't match as expected

Tags: c++, qt, qregexp

Why is the regular expression of Qt a little different? I can match correctly in regular matching software, but not in Qt.
For example.

```
QString tstring = "scale(1.1) rotate(180) translate(1,0)";
QRegExp re("(?<=[\\)])."); 
QStringList tlist = tstring.split(re);
```

I want to separate the three with spaces to get the three QString "scale(1.1)", "rotate(180)" "translate(1,0)"

Comment: Maybe you want to use [`QRegularExpression`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#details) which uses the Perl syntax.

Comment: With which matching software you matched any of these? All I can match with your pattern are the two whitespaces. Your RegExp says: Match one char following a ")" - are you sure, thats what you want?

Comment: Why don't you just do `tstring.split(' ')`?

Comment: I can also match two spaces with the online matching tool, but not in Qt.

Comment: Except for those, some QString are like "matrix (3 1-1 3 30 40)" and cannot be divided directly by spaces.

Comment: Thank you. I succeeded with QRegularExpression.

Comment: What is a _three with spaces_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different syntaxes of regular expressions exist. Qt implements some of them:

- [`QRegularExpression`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#details) (>= Qt5): implements Perl-compatible regular expressions
- [`QRegExp`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#details): implements multiple regular expression forms, see [`QRegExp::PatternSyntax`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#PatternSyntax-enum)

  - `QRegExp::RegExp` (the default): Qt's regexp language modeled on Perl's regexp language
  - `QRegExp::Wildcard`: similar to wildcards used by shells.
  - `QRegExp::W3CXmlSchema11`: implementation of the W3C XML Schema 1.1 specification.
  - ...

Note that [`QRegularExpression` is the recommended one](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#notes-for-qregexp-users):

> The QRegularExpression class introduced in Qt 5 is a big improvement
> upon QRegExp, in terms of APIs offered, supported pattern syntax and
> speed of execution.

A detailed overview of the differences between `QRegExp` and `QRegularExpression` can be found in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#different-pattern-syntax).